# Update default value after selection made

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to achieve what is displayed in the image below:

1. If a user selects an option in event 1, the unselected default value must be updated from "SELECT" to "None". What is currently happening is that it remains "SELECT".

How do I update it to "None"? I am able to update the selected class,  but I am unable to update the unselected value. Have been struggling for days now.
[image]

My Html:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div *ngFor="let event of groupSelections" class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let team of event?.Actors; first as isFirst" class="col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div *ngIf="isFirst" class="col-6">
           <div>
          {{ team?.ActorName }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div [className]="isSelectedPlayer(team?.Players) ?'selected':''">
        <select (change)="getSelections(event, actors)">
          <option value="">SELECT</option>
          <option value="" *ngFor="let player of team?.Players">
            {{ player?.Name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!isFirst" class="col-6">
      <div>
        {{ team?.ActorName }}
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

My Data:

```
groupSelections = [
{
  "PromotionId": 5,
  "Events": [
    {
      "Actors": [
        {
          "ActorId": 33,
          "ActorName": "Italy",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": " Mattia De Sciglio (D)",
              "Position": "DEFENDER",
              "Point": 5
            },
            {
              "Name": "Bryan Cristante (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ActorId": 34,
          "ActorName": "Turkey",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": " Zeki Çelik (D)",
              "Position": "DEFENDER",
              "Point": 5
            },
            {
              "Name": "Ozan Tufan (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Actors": [
        {
          "ActorId": 77,
          "ActorName": "Slovakia",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": "Mattia Perin (G)",
              "Position": "GOALKEEPER",
              "Point": 10
            },
            {
              "Name": "Bryan Cristante (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ActorId": 78,
          "ActorName": "Sweden",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": " Zeki Çelik (D)",
              "Position": "DEFENDER",
              "Point": 5
            },
            {
              "Name": "Ozan Tufan (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Ts file:

```
selectedPlayers: Array<string> = [];

 // check whether the players object is in the list
 isSelectedPlayer(players: any): boolean {
     return this.selectedPlayers.findIndex(element => element === players) > -1;
 }

getSelections(event, actors): any {
    const selections = [];
    this.selectedTeam = actors;
    this.selectedTeamPlayers = actors.Players;
    this.gameEvent = event;

// add the selection to your list, if is not in it
if (this.selectedPlayers.findIndex(element => element === player) === -1) {
    this.selectedPlayers.push(player);
}

selections.push({
    EventId: this.gameEvent.EventId,
    ActorId: this.selectedTeam.ActorId,

    PlayerPosition: this.player.Position,
    PlayerPoint: this.player.Point,
   });
   this.playerSelections = selections;
}
```

Comment: So you need to update the single select 1st value right ? from SELECT to None ?

Comment: Yes, If i choose an option in dropdown, the unselected option on the  opposite side must display "None"

Comment: I ll just post my thoughts in answer section to get more clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do the opposite of what you're doing in your "selected" class: create array that includes the value NOT selected in the group event:

New function in TS file:

```
notSelectedPlayer(players: any): boolean {
  return this.unselectedPlayers.findIndex(element => element.ActorId === players) > -1;
}
```

Then duplicate the function inside your getSelections() but only the unselected value:

```
if (this.gameEvent.Actors.find(item => item.ActorId !== this.selectedTeam.ActorId)) {
  const unselectedValue = this.unselectedPlayers.filter(elem => {
      return elem.ActorId !== this.selectedTeam.ActorId;
  });
  selections2.push(...unselectedValue, {
    EventId: this.gameEvent.EventId,
    ActorId: this.unselectedValue.ActorId,
    EventActorId: this.unselectedValue.EventActorId,
    Score: 0,
    Position: 0,
    PlayerPosition: null,
    PlayerPoint: 0,
    PlayerId: 0
  });
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<select (change)="getSelections(event, actors)">
    <option value="" hidden *ngIf="!notSelectedPlayer(team.ActorId)">SELECT</option>
    <option value="" hidden *ngIf="notSelectedPlayer(team?.ActorId)"> None</option>
    <option value="" *ngFor="let player of team?.Players">
        {{ player?.Name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new attribute in your Data interface parellel to ActorId,ActorName , might be `selected: boolean`
So your data like below,

```
"Actors": [
        {
          "ActorId": 33,
          "ActorName": "Italy",
          "selected": true, // if Italy is selected
           //..... other fields...
        }
    ]
```

So when clicking option in getSelections() method , update the selected boolean value based on ActorId.

In HTML,
Instead of this , `<option value="">SELECT</option>`
Do logic to get SELECT or None value based on the `selected` boolean value from loop.

**Edit 1**

HTML

```
        <option *ngIf="!team.selected && touched" value="">NONE</option>
        <option *ngIf="!touched" value="">SELECT</option>
```

TS

call `reBuildData(event)` from `getSelections(event, actors)`

```
 reBuildData(event) {
    this.touched = true;
    this.groupSelections[0].Events.forEach(event1 => {
      event1.Actors.forEach(actors1 => {
        if (actors1.ActorId == event.ActorId) {
          actors1.selected = true;
        } else {
          actors1.selected = false;
        }
      });
    });
    console.log(this.groupSelections[0]); // check the selected value for all actors.
  }
```

declare this property `touched = false;`

Alter this logic based on your need.

Comment: If possible deploy ur code in stackblitz to help more

Comment: Could you implement your logic in code? Also I cannot change API data. Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ftmajq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Refer answer in same post.(Edit 1)

Comment: Thanks for the help, was unable to get this to work, for some reason if i selected one dropdown the template was adding ng touched to all other dropdowns